# importScripts (web workers)

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have tried to use importScripts to load a second JavaScript file into my web worker, but although no error occurred, it didn't work. I narrowed the problem down to this very simple situation:

In the main HTML file:

```
<script>
var w = new Worker("script1.js");
w.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    alert(e.data);
})
w.postMessage();
</script>
```

In script1.js:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    var a = 5;
    importScripts("script2.js");
    self.postMessage(a);
})
```

In script2.js:

```
a = 6
```

I would like to see a dialog displaying 6, because a was changed from 5 to 6 by importing script2.js, but the dialog shows 5. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could the line after importScripts("script2".js"); -->self.postMessage(a); no longer be referring to the right self because you imported that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using `var a` in the function means that `a` will always be private. Since [importScripts adds to the global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers#Importing_scripts_and_libraries), JS prefers to access the more localized `a` in the function that posts `a`. You can post `self.a` instead, which shall be 6, as you expected.

EDIT: Someone recently asked me about this in person, so I made a demo to clarify the behaviour: http://pagedemos.com/importscript/

Comment: pagedemos.com return a warning from Google Safe Browsing. Can you move it to something like jsfiddle?